# Android stream live audio

Tags: java, android, service, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

I am currently making an app that plays live radio. I made a button in my MainActivity class, which starts the play service like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StreamRadio.class);
startService(intent);
```

Here is the code in my StreamRadio class.

```
public class StreamRadio extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {
    private static final String TAG = "Information progress";
    public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http:/xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/");
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected to http:/xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx");
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            Log.d(TAG, "Preparing Async");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "IOException");
        }
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Mediaplayer prepared");
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        Log.d(TAG, "Nearly finished");

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "Service is destroyed");

        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

When the button in MainActivity is clicked again, the service is stopped.

The service gets started and destroyed on click. This is the logcat output (physical device):

```
02-03 09:42:05.719 9318-9318/ D/Information progress: Connected to http:/81.18.165.234:8361
02-03 09:42:05.719 9318-9318/ D/Information progress: Preparing Async
02-03 09:42:05.719 9318-9318/ D/Information progress: Nearly finished
02-03 09:42:05.729 9318-9318/ E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1)
```

On an emulator I get this error:

```
02-03 10:08:26.054 2797-2797/ D/Information progress: Connected to http:/81.18.165.234:8361
02-03 10:08:26.055 2797-2797/ D/Information progress: Preparing Async
02-03 10:08:26.056 2797-2797/ D/Information progress: Nearly finished
02-03 10:08:26.060 2797-2808/ E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
02-03 10:08:26.060 2797-2797/ E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
```

So I guess my question is as follows:
Why is prepareAsync not working correctly, since there's no logcat message "Mediaplayer prepared", and how can I solve this?
I gave the app internet permission in the manifest. Other problems on SO don't seem to be the same as mine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in your **datasource**, check if you are assigning **"Stream URL"** to your datasource. e.g. http://live.streamtheworld.com:80/WXYZFMMOBILECMP3

**OR**

Try the link below, It may help:
https://github.com/tjnicolaides/Radio-Station-Stream-App-for-Android

Comment: I used the same datasource before, outside a service, and it worked fine. Thanks for the link!

Comment: In the code from the link you provided, they are using mediaPlayer.prepare(). When I use prepare(), it won't play music, but it doesn't throw an error either. 

Do you know a way to solve it with prepareAsync?